# Billing name not included in message template: Receipt (on-line)

Tags: message-templates

The billing name is not showing in the message template: Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line).

The template is using $billingName to get the billing name.

The billing address is showing, using, $address|nl2br.

I don't think civi keep a record of the billing name contribution record?

Other info:

The billing name is showing on the eWay dashboard.

I am Using webform_civicrm to take payment.

Maybe related issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18027

Using CiviCRM 5.3.0

Comment: Best if you mention the civi version you are on

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the version.

Comment: I think the core contribution pages DO record the billing address when a credit card payment is submitted so this might be something missing in webform_civicrm